# Protect PostgreSQL database connection

Tags: php, security, postgresql

I'm currently working on a php/PostgreSQL/JQuery project, and I'm an absolute beginner in all of these domains. In Php, to connect to my database, best way I found was to include a php
script with user and password in all php scripts that need it, like this.
`include('../scripts/pgconnect.php');`

With pgconnect.php :

`$conn_string = "dbname=mydb user=myuser password=mypass";`

`$db = pg_connect($conn_string);`

`if(!$db){` 
 `die("Connection à la base impossible -> " . pg_errormessage($db));}`

I'm sure all of you security expert will laugh at this, so could you tell me what is the best way to keep user and pass out from prying eyes ?
I found on stack overflow an advice to use env variables, but I don't find it really secure.

Comment: You can accept one (!) answer by clicking the V on the left side of the answer. It'll keep people motivated to answer to your future questions. So, select the best answer please.

Answer (score 4):

PHP is a server-side language. That means that when the requested page is sent back to the client all PHP code is parsed and "removed". As long you're the only one being able to look into your files there is no fear.

Whether you store it in (env) variables or not won't make a single difference.

There's absolutely nothing wrong with this code ;)

---

Edit:

When you execute an SQL query however, you need to be careful. Often, you use user input (an URL or POST data) to set certain values in a query. For example:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`=' . $_GET['id'];
```

The `$_GET['id']` variable is set in the URL (`index.php?id=4`).

If they change the value `4` to a bit of SQL query, they can pretty much do everything with your database. This is called [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). It's truly the biggest threat of web applications using a database.

There are multiple fixes.

- Sanitize the input (make sure that the input doesn't contain SQL syntax)
- Prepare statements

Now, I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL, but apparently the PHP module has the ability to send prepared statements. This allows you to send the query with the unknown values as question marks and send the values afterwards.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id`=?';
// send prepared statement

$value = $_GET['id'];
// send the value
```

This way the database can tell that the value is no query.

Like I said, I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL, but I'm sure there are some tutorials that will guide you all the way through!

---

Another edit:

Because I'm a nice guy, I found how to do it! You need to use the function [pg_prepare()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-prepare.php) and [pg_execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php). Like this:

```
// This is a name to allow the database to identify the prepared statement
$queryname = 'my_query';

// Setting up our query with "empty" values
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `column`='$1' AND `column`='$2'";

// Setting our values to send afterwards
$values = array(
    $_GET['first_value'], // The first value that will replace $1
    $_GET['second_value'] // The second value that will replace $2
);

$result = pg_prepare($connection, $queryname, $sql); // Send the query to the database
$result = pg_execute($connection, $queryname, array($value)); // Send the values
```

---

Last edit (I swear):

If you decide to put your configuration variables in an extern file, lets say configuration.php, make sure that the file ends with the `.php` extension. If you use a different extension, people might be able to find it and see it in plain text. If the PHP extension is used, they won't be able to see anything because like I said, the PHP is parsed and removed.

Comment: Sorry, but this is terrible advice. You should *never* keep your database password in plain text, especially not in your PHP files.

Comment: @AviD PHP is parsed before sent to the client, they don't get to see the password. Unless someone has direct access to your files on the server, there is no threat. Why do you think the world's leading CMS save database passwords in PHP files in plain text? If it's such a big issue like you say, what do you suggest? Even if you would encrypt it, you would still have to decrypt it. When a hacker has access to your server files, they can look up the decrypting algorithm too. If you would use any other extension, the text is not parsed and will be shown in plain text which is even worse.

Comment: Of course it doesnt get sent to the client. Unless there is an error. Or some vulnerability. Or an insider access to the files. Or... Why would the world's leading CMS save files in plain text PHP files? I have no clue. Apparently neither do they. The rest of your comment is senseless, and displays a complete misunderstanding of encryption, protection, and security. I suggest you do a little bit of homework on these subjects before you call yourself a professional developer.

Comment: Sorry that I'm being so harsh, but you really need to WAKE UP to the realities of insecure development and the real risks this exposes you to. We keep hearing about these big exploits of some of the biggest companies, it all starts with things like this. And it's not just you, of course.

Comment: Errors doesn't display the raw PHP source code. Insider access can still browse through all source code and backtrack the original credentials. I doubt the huge communities behind leading CMS would ignore security issues. I've done enough homework to know that hacks rarely have anything to do with how passwords are stored on web applications. In most cases it's just poor user input validation. That goes for XSS, SQL injection and file inclusion. I know you are an expert at this, so what do you suggest we do? What is your advice?

Comment: Most real world exploits are ALL about how passwords are stored on web applications. Almost every single large-scale exploit is *exactly* that. What you're saying about browsing source code is not an answer, it is the problem - no credentials should be in code. Have you never heard of Kerckhoff's Principle? Unfortunately, I am not well versed in PHP, that's why I was looking for PHP-specific solutions - there ARE solutions, starting with never keeping passwords in plain text.

Comment: If one has access to a raw PHP file, he has access to the file system, yes? So when if we save the credentials elsewhere and encrypted, it would still be accessible for the exploiter. So would the decrypting engine and the key required to decrypt. It does make it harder, but far from impossible to secure the credentials, right? It's a start though.

Comment: No, you use proper hashing, so that compromised credentials *cannot* be easily reversed to plaintext. For example, you could use bcrypt or PBKDF2 to hash the password, and store that hash. On login, you hash the input password and compare it against the target hash - if it matches then the password is correct. You should **NEVER** use reversible (e.g. symmetric) encryption for passwords. Jump over to [IT Security StackExchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) and dig around in some of the highest voted questions for an intro to proper password security.

Comment: I also don't know why you'd think storing hard-coded passwords for users in PHP files is a good idea. If it's a shared product, that's called a backdoor and will *definitely* be classed as security vulnerability. I also recommend you take a look at the [OWASP Top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main) for a nice list of the top vulnerabilities in webapps. Notice that [A7](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-A7) is about insufficient storage security. This has been promoted to [A6](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A6) in the 2013 release candidate.

Comment: (Note that @Polynomial's comment re hashing with bcrypt et al refers to user passwords, not the database password, obviously. This is just useful advice, in general, since you seem blissfully unaware of how to store passwords.)

Comment: I always store user passwords with a one-way hash. This is the oldest trick in the book. Apart from that, risk no. A7 refers to other risks of how unencrypted data is obtained. It points to no. A4 and A8. If you validate your user input well and are careful with what you display, they can't read the configuration file through an exploit in your web application. From that point you would have to exploit the webserver's software, which is beyond my knowledge. But when they do break in the webserver, they still have access to everything which includes decrypt algorithms and encrypted data.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what @TimS. is saying. From the beginning he was talking about saving the Database connection's credentials in the `.php` file and not the users' credentials. AviD was wrong in his first comment as there's no secure alternative to storing the Database's password in plaintext. In the later comments both Poly and AviD started talking about users' passwords and Tim stayed on the Database's password, which created a misunderstanding. While Poly's comments are valuable and indeed correct, they have nothing to do with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use environment variable to store db authentication information: that is, the host/user/password for the db are in SetEnv commands in the Apache configuration, which appear in `$_SERVER`.

Why do this?

1. Development and production environments need different values for these, so having the application read some sort of environment configuration is necessary.
2. The application code is in a source code repository, which is easily browseable... embedding authentication secrets into it would make those just as widely available.

Environment variables aren't the only solution: for example, including a file that sets up a configuration object of some sort will work too. But most people seem to evolve some system for having the configuration settings (and just the settings) in a single changeable point, separate from the code that uses those settings, which changes on a completely different schedule.

Comment: Thank you all for your advices. I'll read carefully pg_prepare documentation (didn't know about that) think again to env variables for user / pass information.